# Adding mongoose schema model to express results in error 500

Tags: express, mongoose

I have react app that stores data via axios to a mongoose server. It worked perfect until I wanted to add an extra schema for different data. My schema models are separated so I thought to just add another one called **PartyList.js**.

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

// Define collection and schema for Items
var PartyList = new Schema({
  name: {
    type: String
  },
  song_id: {
    type: String
  },
  port: {
      type: Number
  }
},{
    collection: 'party'
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('PartyList', PartyList);
```

This is the code in my app.js.

```
const config = require('./database/DB');
const ServerPortRouter = require('./routes/ServerPortRoutes');

mongoose.connect(config.DB).then(
    () => {console.log('Database is connected') },
    err => { console.log('Can not connect to the database' +err)
});

app.use('/serverport', ServerPortRouter);
```

This is how I import it and try to run it (called ServerPortRoutes.js). After running a part of my application that uses this route I get a 50**0 (Internal Server Error)**. My server tells me **ReferenceError: PartyList is not defined** which is defined 3 lines above.

```
const ServerPort = require('../models/ServerPort');
const PartyList = require('../models/PartyList');

ServerPortRouter.route('/add-party').post(function (req, res) {
  const PartyList = new PartyList(req.body);
  PartyList.save()
    .then(PartyList => {
        res.json('Server added successfully');
    })
    .catch(err => {
    res.status(500).send("unable to save to database");
    });
});
```

Comment: You have two const as the same name. Rename the PartyList in the route

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem looks to be you are redefining a const . In your route change to `const partyList = new PartyList(req.body);` Then use `partyList` as your variable